# MVC 4 :Calling Api controller from View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a Web Api controller method from a view using Ajax. 
My ajax call from the view is as follows,

```
function loginuser() {
    var name = $("#txt_usrname").val();
    var pass = $("#txt_password").val();
    var source = {
        'username': name,
        'password': pass,
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: source,
        url: 'api/Login', // url of Api controller not mvc
        success: function (data) {
              if(data.redirect)
                alert("Redirect true !");

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm able to call the api controller from any view except in the following scenario.

After setting the login url in webconfig as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" path="/" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
```

The ~/Account/Login points to an MVC controller. If I call the api controller using ajax
from ~/Account/Login view , the ajax call is mapped to the MVC controller ~/Account/Login instead of the Api Controller api/Login. But if I remove the 'authentication' tag from web.config and load Account/Login as default view, the ajax call is mapped to the api Controller as expected.

I tried changing the url in ajax call, but no matter what the url is, the ajax call is always mapped to the MVC controller instead of the controller name I'm giving as url.

This happens only for the Loginurl view inside  authentication tag. If I remove the authentication tag and use the ajax call in any other view, it works fine.

Has anyone come across this problem?, sorry if I'm missing the obvious, But I've been stuck on this for hours...

I need all actions to be handled by Api controllers , not MVC , because the project is to be used with Phonegap.

Any help, advice, even if not an answer will be much appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Here's my route table

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and for webApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself..
The authentication I used restricts calling controller methods other than the one used as loginUrl. Therefore all references to controllers other than Account\login are mapped to Account\login itself.

Used [authorize] attribute on controllers to overcome this issue.